# Why does SELECT * FROM TAB return a more records than SELECT COL... FROM TAB?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data constellation in Oracle where I cannot explain why `select * from <table>` would return a different number of records than `select <col-1>, <col-2>,.. from <table>`:

This is a trimmed down version to demonstrate the phenomenon:

```
create table tq84_tab (
   id          number(7)    not null,
   val_1       number(4,1)  not null,
   val_2       varchar2(10) not null
);

create table tq84_flg (
   tab_rowid   rowid
);

create or replace view tq84_v_s_t_hist_anton as
select
   tab.*,
   case when flg.tab_rowid is not null then 1 else 0 end flg
from
   tq84_tab   tab                                left join
   tq84_flg   flg on tab.rowid = flg.tab_rowid
;


begin
   insert into tq84_tab values( 10001, 4.2, 'XXX');
   insert into tq84_tab values( 10002, 5.1, 'YYY');
--
-- Insert same rowid twice!
--
   insert into tq84_flg(tab_rowid) select rowid from tq84_tab where val_2 = 'YYY';
   insert into tq84_flg(tab_rowid) select rowid from tq84_tab where val_2 = 'YYY';

   commit;
end;
/
```

With this date, I get:

```
SQL> select *            from tq84_v_s_t_hist_anton;

        ID      VAL_1 VAL_2             FLG
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     10002        5.1 YYY                 1
     10002        5.1 YYY                 1
     10001        4.2 XXX                 0
```

However, with the following query, I get two records only:

```
SQL> select val_1, val_2 from tq84_v_s_t_hist_anton;

     VAL_1 VAL_2     
---------- ----------
       4.2 XXX       
       5.1 YYY
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/MQof-KlJ

I am really not sure how I can explain this behavior.

Comment: This is a bug obviously. (I have added a demo to your request, so others can see that this is really happening.) Well, you should never store rowids in a table to reference another table's rows of course, but it's still a bug.

Comment: If you join on ROWIDTOCHAR(tab.rowid) = ROWIDTOCHAR(flg.tab_rowid) the 3 rows are displayed

Comment: Works fine with 11gR2

Comment: Regarding: "insert into tq84_flg(tab_rowid) select rowid from tq84_tab where val_2 = 'YYY';   insert into tq84_flg(tab_rowid) select rowid from tq84_tab where val_2 = 'YYY';" should one of the 'YYY' be 'XXX' ?